# Yup validar CPF

Tags: javascript, react, typescript, yup

Como que eu posso utilizar o Yup para validar o cpf?
Eu já tenho uma função que checa se é um CPF válido ou não, mas não sei como utilizar ela dentro do shape do Yup...

Comment: Utilize o método [`Schema.test`](https://github.com/jquense/yup#schematestname-string-message-string--function--any-test-function-schema). Se você não conseguir, edite sua pergunta e coloque o código que você tentou.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode tentar usar o método `test` do Yup:

```js
(async () => {
try {
  const schema = Yup.object().shape({
        cpf: Yup.string().test(
                  'test-invalid-cpf',
                  'cpf inválido',
                  (cpf) =>  cpfIsInvalid(cpf))
  })
  await schema.validate({ cpf: "123.123.123-12" })
} catch (err) {
  throw new Error (err.message)
}
})()
```

- Se o retorno do `test` for `false`, então dispara a mensagem de erro, no caso "cpf inválido"
- É importante que a key passada no `schema.validate` esteja igual à key de shape, para que possa fazer a comparação
- O erro irá cair no catch

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).